# CSS apply styles according to screen resolution

Tags: css

I have a CSS class like:

```
.container {
    padding-left: 150px;
}
```

What I want is when the screen resolution is tablet or mobile I want the `padding-left` to be like `10px` only.

How can I do this?

Comment: By using [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Examples) queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet and mobile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Comment: You can make some search on Google too

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS [`@media query`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to do it. You provide `breakpoints` as its argument, as for example [here](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints).

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

[..etc..]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Media Queries. Just for your reference example I've taken screen sizes as a reference from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

```
/* For Mobile Phones */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
}

/* For Tablets (Portrait) */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .container {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!